# In PyCharm, how do I enable breakpoints that will activate in a file that is not the startup file?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I hope this a real simple one that I just missed. I am setting up a development environment for a python-driven web application, and I can't seem to get my breakpoints in files outside of the startup file to pause when the code runs past them.

I have set up the **Configuration** correctly, as far as I know. The application starts and runs correctly with what I have set. I am able to set a breakpoint inside the file that is specified in the **Script path**, and when I start Debug mode this breakpoint is hit. But, if I set one in a file that is outside of this file, they get passed and the code continues to run.

What would I need to do to activate breakpoints in any file in a project, whenever the execution runs over the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item I was looking for was **Attach to Local Process**. This allows me to attach a debugger to any running process, and breakpoints will be hit whenever they are hit in running code once the debugger is attached to the right process.

I found this by troubleshooting the many options in the toolbar. Sometimes it is just a matter of playing around with something until you find it yourself, or knowing the right words to search...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly old question but I stumbled across it while searching for a solution for the same problem. I solved it by editing the breakpoint (Alt + Enter) and changing the suspend option from 'Thread' to 'All'.

[image: Edit breakpoint]

[image: Suspend option]